# what is pending_update_count in telegram bot?

Tags: php, mysql, telegram, telegram-bot

i have a [telegram](/questions/tagged/telegram)bot that works fine (i developed it with [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)).
but sometimes it's not working, and when i send **getWebhookInfo**, sends me a message that includes **pending_update_count**.

1. what is pending_update_count?
2. how to prevent pending_update_count filling?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the problem is from bad communication
Between Telegram and your link and when it doesn't get 200
Gives a failed connection and hangs your messages

Answer (score 0):

`pending_update_count` is the number of messages that your bot has not been received and is in queue to be received. Maybe your web hook does not respond with 200 status to Telegram (e.g. returns 500 cause of an error).

Comment: how to prevent that?

Comment: @mo30 Add `getWebhookInfo` results into your post. It shows last error. You should log all requests to see potential errors.